# Is there a complete python wrapper for the maas api?

Tags: 16.04, python, maas

I have been looking for a fully baked python wrapper for the MAAS API but all I have found is this: https://github.com/maas/python-libmaas It seems to be rather incomplete so I was hoping someone might know if something else existed. I am working with MAAS 2.1.x but I am just looking for any complete wrapper for the 2.0 API